# Hi, What will be the software stack needed if we are using WordPress for developing GIS application?

Tags: wordpress, gis

I need to know what software stack to use when developing a GIS application using WordPress.
Can we build sophisticated GIS web applications in WordPress.

I am exploring ways to incorporate GIS with WordPress.
I have used google, but I have not been to enough idea to get started.

Thanks in advance
Arun G

Answer (score 0):

For WordPress, you don't need to go for a specific stack. LEMP or LAMP anyone can work.

You need to find a specific plugin either on WordPress plugins directory or some marketplaces like CodeCanyon.